# SSRS Group Filter not being applied to grouping by

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have group properties that include filters, and it works when the tablix is itemized. But if I try to group it per variety and per year, the sum of the area does not take into account these group filters.  It returns the total sum, regardless of the filters set on the group.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the filter as a grouping as well. So Group on Commercial, then variety name, then year, allowed the sum to aggregate properly.  I'm not sure why this worked, and if someone has advice, I would appreciate it.

Comment: This might explain it. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b8137fdc-2aaf-4289-a966-05dcef7a21a6/ssrs-2012-group-filter-does-not-apply-to-group-total?forum=sqlreportingservices

Also, looking at your other question, you might be better to re-think how you are grouping data. Sometimes easier to create separate datasets so you don't have to worry about filtering in the report groups.